# Output Export to excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

We having SQL Server Management Studio , we had written several stored procedures in it. Currently we taking output in `HTML` and mailing to desired email id's. Now our requirement is instead of `HTML` we need to take output in excel and mail to desired Id's.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926. Otherwise you need to give us far more information to be able to help. Show us snippets of the code that is constructing the HTML, and the code that is doing the emailing

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SQL Server Reporting services, and add subscriptions that send the created result by email as an Excel or CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question.

As Michael mentioned, you may use SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) to create a report that automatically sends the excel file to your chosen subscribers.

This might be an ideal solution if:

1. Your business unit would like the report to have specific fonts, color schemes, and column formatting as this is a user-friendly way to format the report and test as needed prior to adding on the email subscriptions. Of course, this depends on your audience and the way that the excel file might be used.
2. You have support analysts or specialists on your team that have been granted access to SSRS, but not necessarily SQL Server Management Studio.  From my experience, granting access to one but not the other may lessen the liability of stored procedures or tables being written over, deleted, executed improperly, etc.
3. Your business unit frequently has changes to the subscription list, as you would be able to hand the responsibility of editing the list over to designated user-support team members rather than bogging down your SQL Developers.

However, if you'd prefer to create a stored procedure to send the emails or don’t have access to SSRS, then you should be able to use the Bulk Copy Program (BCP) command-line utility to generate a simple CSV file.  Here are a couple of resources that provide further detail on this option:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/453c9593-a689-4f7e-8364-fa998e266363/how-to-export-sql-data-to-excel-spreadsheet-using-sql-query?forum=transactsql

If you have any further questions, please don’t hesitate to reach out!  I’m always happy to help whenever I’m able.